# How to convert to a Date from Timestamp

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

The two below JSON valus (created, udated) are some type of timestamp.  The provider (Edmunds API) didn't specify anything besides "timestamp".  I have tried standard UNIX conversion to .Net Datetime but nothing is working.

"created":**1380292641721**,"updated":**1380312585558**

The following two methods didn't work:

```
 internal DateTime ConvertUnixEpochTime(long epoch)
    {
        long baseTicks = 621355968000000000;
        long tickResolution = 10000000;

        //long epoch = 1225815911;

        long epochTicks = (epoch * tickResolution) + baseTicks;
        return new DateTime(epochTicks, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    }

    public DateTime UnixTimeStampToDateTime(long unixTimeStamp)
    {
        // Unix timestamp is seconds past epoch
        System.DateTime dtDateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        dtDateTime = dtDateTime.AddSeconds(unixTimeStamp).ToLocalTime();
        return dtDateTime;
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you create such a timestamp in a way so that you know which actual time it represents? Or better multiple ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `AddMilliseconds` instead of `AddSeconds`

```
System.DateTime dtDateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
dtDateTime = dtDateTime.AddMilliseconds(1380312585558).ToLocalTime();
```

Answer (score 4):

Your current code assumes the value is in *seconds* - whereas it looks like it's in *milliseconds* since the Unix epoch. So you want:

```
private static readonly DateTime UnixEpoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0,
                                                          DateTimeKind.Utc);

...

DateTime dateTime = UnixEpoch.AddMilliseconds(value);
```

Or using [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org):

```
Instant instant = Instant.FromMillisecondsSinceUnixEpoch(value);
```